# jQuery Push Values into an Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

What i'm trying to do is pushing values into an array like below:

```
var travellers = [['travellerUsername1', 'travellerFullname1'],['travellerUsername2', 'travellerFullname2'], ['travellerUsername3', 'travellerFullname3']]

$.each(travellers, function(index, value){
    options = [
        {label: value, title: value, value: index}
    ];
});
```

But as you can see this is just initiating the last data into my options object.
**How can i push each travellers value into my options object?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Array#push` method to push `object` in `array`

```js
var travellers = [
  ['travellerUsername1', 'travellerFullname1'],
  ['travellerUsername2', 'travellerFullname2'],
  ['travellerUsername3', 'travellerFullname3']
]
var options = [];
$.each(travellers, function(index, value) {
  options.push({
    label: value,
    title: value,
    value: index
  });
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(options, null, 4));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Think i was digging so much and wasn't able to see the simple path.

Comment: @blankBird_  – I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_